# How to store queried custom data and use it in multiple pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, pages

```
<?php
                    $contact = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'contact'
                        // 'post_status' => 'publish'
                    ));
                    while($contact -> have_posts()){
                        $contact -> the_post();
                        $watsapp = get_field('watsapp_no');
                        $mobile = get_field('mobile_no');
                        $telephone = get_field('telephone_no');
                        $address = get_field('address');
                    }
                    wp_reset_query();
                    ?>
```

- I need to echo the contact details in multiple pages
- Do i need to call it in each page  or  there is any simple way to not
  repeating the same query?

Answer (score -1):

Though it's not clear exactly what do you want. But, you can do this by two ways.

1. Make a Function like

   ```
            function wpse_1001(){
              $contact = new WP_Query(array(
              'post_type' => 'contact'
                   // 'post_status' => 'publish'
               ));
               while($contact -> have_posts()){
                   $contact -> the_post();
                   $watsapp = get_field('watsapp_no');
                   $mobile = get_field('mobile_no');
                   $telephone = get_field('telephone_no');
                   $address = get_field('address');
               }
               wp_reset_query();
             }
   ```

Use the Code anywhere on your Code.

2. You can Use Shortcodes by `add_shortcode()`, so that you can use it from your Editor also.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

If you like Shortcodes then you can use on your Code by `do_shortcode()` function.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/